# How can I change the "connect to team server as" user in TFS 2013 server?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

In Team Foundation Server 2013 I cannot seem to change "connect to team server as" user.

TFS server is pointing to our Visual Studio Online https://ourtfs.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection and the the account that the TFS server is using to checkout code is also "Account Service (ourtfs)" even though there is no such account on our network!
(The current user seems to be one made up when the VSO was setup!)

How can I change it to checkout our code using a network account?

See the "Connect to Team Foundation Server as:" in the dialog below, in our case the account is "Account Service (ourtfs)".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are configuring a local build controller or agent to talk to VSO then this is the correct account.

Every VSO account has a "service account" that can be used for unattended access. When you connect the build service it uses your MSA/AAD credentials to retrieve this account and password from VSO and configured the build service to use it.

That's the only way it works as an MSA/AAD token only lasts for 48 hours and you don't want to be relogging in every 2 days.

http://nakedalm.com/tools/vso-service-credential-viewer/

I have an app that can retrieve the credentials if you need to use them outside of the build service.

Comment: That explains the account but I dont see how it may fix my issue. How can I checkout items through my build if its using this "service account"?

Comment: I also see that the app requires "Team Explorer 2015" which I dont have.

Comment: Team explorer is free and available as part of Visual Studio 2015 on http://visual studio.com

Comment: Well that would be great. I got TFS Workspace errors when a checkout was attempted. I've since deleted the log file. I'll recreate it.

Comment: We're just moving to 2013 so 2015 is not an option right now.

Comment: If you email me the log I can take a look

Comment: Thanks Ive just emailed you.

Comment: MrHinsh has found the solution for me, thanks for your time. The issue with checking out files with the Service Account was that I was still using tf.exe from VS 2010 instead of VS2013, I've fixed up my scripts and now the checkout is working.

Comment: Just to clarify, Ensure your scripts are using tf.exe from VS2013 and not VS2010 i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"